# GestureDetector tab does not work after rotation in Flutter

Tags: flutter

There is an icon under the image widget and I can rotate the image using `GestureDetector` and `Transform.rotate`.

At first, it works well to rotate the image by dragging the icon.
However, tapping the icon again after rotating does not work.

Can you tell me the cause and solution of this?

```
  Transform.rotate(
    angle: imageModel.radians,
    child: Stack(
      // image widget 

        // TODO image rotate icon
        // left bottom
        Positioned(
          left: -5,
          bottom: -5,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onPanStart: (details) {
                logger.d("rotate click");
                _imageStartPoint = details.globalPosition;
              },
              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                double initX = _imageStartPoint.dx;
                double initY = _imageStartPoint.dy;

                // moving distance?
                var dragX = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
                var dragY = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;

                // The direction of the drag and the direction of rotation are opposite
                double degrees = -dragX; 
                double radiams = 0; 

                // rignt drag
                if (dragX < 0) {
                  radiams = degrees * math.pi / 180;
                } else {
                  radiams = degrees * math.pi / 180;
                }

                imageModel.radians = radiams;
                _imageStreamController.add(imageModel);
              },

              child: const Icon(
                Icons.rotate_right,
                size: 30,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
        ),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Can you  provide full widget that will reproduce the issue. Tested on general basis `onPanStart` is working after rotation